# Facebook Graph API - update post date

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to create post on facebook (using graph API) with changed date or update this post and change date of them?

Here you can check info about posting using the Facebook Graph API

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/post/
>
> Check this:
>
> created_time
>
> The time the post was initially published. For a post about a life
>   event, this will be the date and time of the life event
>
> datetime Hope it helps

I viewed this site and section `publishing posts` redirect to `{user-id}/feed` when there isn't option which can change date of post.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/post#updating "You can update any of the fields, except link, listed in the Publishing sections of the /{user-id}/feed, /{page-id}/feed, /{event-id}/feed, or /{group-id}/feed edges."

Comment: I am using `echo exec("curl --data 'backdated_time=111212121&message=testupdate&privacy=".urlencode('{"value":"EVERYONE"}')."&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/100011042287799_305167736527967/");` and result is: `{"error":{"message":"(#100) Unsupported post request. (Operation only used for Pages)","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"Ge3oW6AeeB+"}}`

Comment: I would like to change date of my post using my profile, not page.

Comment: "Operation only used for Pages" sounds clear enough. Does it work without the `backdated_time` bit? That parameter is not listed on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/user/feed.

Comment: Yes, it works without `backdated_time` parameter. I would like to know is it other way to do that.

Comment: Based on the docs and the error message you're getting, it's not possible. Backdating posts appears to be limited to pages.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can check info about posting using the Facebook Graph API

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/post/

Check this:

> created_time
>
> The time the post was initially published. For a post
>   about a life event, this will be the date and time of the life event
>
> datetime

Hope it helps

Comment: Publishing posts redirect to {user-id}/feed when there isn't option which can change date of post.

Comment: I figured it out. You need to use "backdated_time" and the format of the time needs to be in "ISO 8601 date" format.